# The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'RamalAguia.Models.Setor' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Durante a realização de um projeto me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'RamalAguia.Models.Setor' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

**Esse é meu Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PreparaFormulario();            
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RamalModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Ramais.Add(model);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ID });
        }
        else
        {
            PreparaFormulario();
            return View();
        }

    }    

    [HttpGet]
    public void PreparaFormulario()
    {
        var setores = new List<Setor>();
        using (RamaDb db = new RamaDb())
        {
            setores = db.Setores.ToList();
        }
        ViewBag.ID2 = new SelectList(_db.Setores, "setorID", "setorNome");


    }
```

**A View:**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.setores, (SelectList)ViewBag.ID2)
```

**E o Model:**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace RamalAguia.Models
 {
 public class RamalModel
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O número é obrigatório.")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }



    public Setor setores { get; set; }
```

Como posso arrumar?

**Edit**

**Obs:** eu consegui achar esse erro por meio de um breakpoint no    ModelState.IsValid, quando a aplicação vai salvar os dados passados, dentro dos values que eu uso para salvar o setor.

**Model do Setor**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace RamalAguia.Models
 {
    public class Setor
    {
       public int setorID { get; set; }

       public string setorNome { get; set; }

       public Area areas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**

**Classes:**

RamalModel

```
    public class RamalModel
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O número é obrigatório.")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }


    public int SetorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SetorId")]
    public Setor setores { get; set; }
```

Setores

```
    public class Setor
    {
    public int setorID { get; set; }

    public string setorNome { get; set; }

    public Area areas { get; set; }
```

E o dbcontext

```
    namespace RamalAguia.Models
    {
        public class RamaDb : DbContext
        {
             public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

             public DbSet<RamalModel> Ramais { get; set; }

             public DbSet<Setor> Setores { get; set; }

             public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seus relacionamento pelo visto estão errados, ***cade a chave da entidade***  `Setor`?

Seria mais ou menos isso, já que não colocou a outra classe da relação:

```
public class RamalModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O número é obrigatório.")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public int SetorId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SetorId")]
    public Setor setores { get; set; }
}

public class Setor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SetorId")]
    public ICollection<RamalModel> RamalModel {get;set;}
}
```

Naquele `DropDownList` ficaria assim então:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetorId", (SelectList)ViewBag.ID2)
```

ou faça assim que é mais usual:

No controller crie um ViewBag com o mesmo nome da chave da relação que é SetorId, siga o modelo:

```
ViewBag.SetorId = new SelectList(_db.Setores, "setorID", "setorNome");
```

e seu `DropDownList` com esse modelo:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetorId")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém quando vou fazer update na base de dados aparece isso no Package Manager Console: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SetorId', table 'RamalAguia.Models.RamaDb.dbo.RamalModels'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Como estão suas tabelas, me passe isso por favor. Você esta mandando item sem valor esse é o erro.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RamalModels] (
    [ID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Numero]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [setores_setorID] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RamalModels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RamalModels_dbo.Setors_setores_setorID] FOREIGN KEY ([setores_setorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Setors] ([setorID])
);

Comment: Tem erro na geração da sua tabelas o problema esta ai.

Comment: Coloque todas as classes e seu dbcontext para eu te ajudar

Comment: Vou colocar em uma nova resposta, melhor vou editar.